# Возможно ли интегрировать streamlit-lightweight-charts в html страницу, используя flask?

Tags: python, html, html5, flask, диаграммы

https://github.com/freyastreamlit/streamlit-lightweight-charts
Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом я могу (если могу) поместить такой график на html странице с кастомными данными, используя flask?

Подразумевается что на странице будет 6-12 графиков подобного вида
https://freyastreamlit-streamlit-lightw-examplespricevolumechart-j8ldyo.streamlit.app/

Answer (score 0):

**Рекомендую перед тем как задавать вопрос немного поискать ответ в гугле**
*Отвечу вам максимально кратко*
Для создания графиков в HTML почитайте 2 статьи
[Как создавать простые графики](https://htmlbook.ru/blog/grafiki-i-diagrammy)
[Как создавать графики с интерактивом](https://kisameev.ru/html5/interaktivnye-grafiki-diagrammy-na-html5)
А далее подставляете свои данные | ПРИМЕР ⬇ |

```
  <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
  <script>
   google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
   function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
     ['Год', 'Россия', 'США'],
     ['1860', 1.3, 70],
     ['1885', 2000, 3120],
     ['1901', 12170, 9920]
    ]);
    var options = {
     title: 'Добыча нефти',
     hAxis: {title: 'Год'},
     vAxis: {title: 'Тыс. тонн'}
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('oil'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
   }
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="oil" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>
 </body>
```

Вместо `Года` или `Страны` подставляете нужные вам параметры вот так -> `{var1}`

> Надеюсь смог донести вам что вы спросили )